# Tortilla Espinoza — what is it and how do I make it?

Tags: spanish-cuisine, tortilla

It's been requested that I make a traditional Spanish dish named *tortilla espinoza*.  I have no idea what this is, and Google has failed me in finding something remotely close to it.

Does anyone know what it is and could point me to a recipe?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't tortilla Espanola? Also, recipe requests are off topic here on Seasoned Advice. As you've also included a question regarding what the item is, I won't vote to close, but you might want to modify the question a little.

Answer (score 3):

...or Tortilla de Espinacas?  This is a dish from Spain where a tortilla is a potato and egg dish made in a low-sided, oven-proof skillet.  This particular version uses spinach - hence "Espinacas".

http://herbivoracious.com/2012/02/tortilla-de-espinaca-spanish-omelet.html

I'm not sure if this is what you might be looking for but I can't wait to try it!